# How can I fill a small gap in a sink drain pipe?

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing a bathroom sink. I messed up (long story, I already forgot the ugly details) by grinding out the piece that the P trap slides into, messing up the threads on the inside of the pipe coming out of the wall. I keep making trips to hardware stores thinking I'm finally getting something that will fit just right but nothing produces anything close to a tight fit, not even the soft adapter with a hose clamp (which would also require a bigger hole in the drywall for tightening the clamp).

I have something that fits loosely over the pipe coming out of the wall. My question is if there is a filler I can use in there to make it a snug fit that can hold up over time? I'm guessing regular plumber's putty would erode?

If not, I'm open to other ideas. The pipe only sticks out of the wall about 1/2".

Comment: You don't want something that fits tightly *over* the pipe in the wall, you want something that fits tightly *in to* the pipe in the wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No to fillers.  Also no to epoxy.  Hire a plumber and get it fixed right. Small leaks, especially those at a sink, turn into rotten cabinets, rotten sub floor, smelly mildew, possibly mold and an unhappy spouse.  Don't go cheap and regret it forever.